# Do I have to generate a rigify rig to make animations for a game?

Tags: rigging

I'm pretty new to rigging with rigify but the rigs that rigify generates are consistently a hassle compared to just using the metarig bones to animate. I'm using the 3d model for a game in unity, is it possible to just animate using the bones while never generating a rig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If animating using a rigify-generated rig is "a hassle", animating using the rigify meta-rig will be a bigger one, so I recommend that you learn how to effectively use the generated rig.

That said, yes, you can use the meatarig.  Simply parent the original mesh to the metarig the same way you would parent the mesh to generated rig; don't create a generated rig; and do your animation with the metarig in pose mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although in what way is using the meta rig to animate a hassle?

Comment: There is no support for inverse kinematics, a technique that often makes positioning limbs much easier.  Several features that reduce the need for compensating for movement in one part of the rig so that another part doesn't move when it's not supposed to are missing, resulting in the animator having to counter-animate things like head position when the torso bends.   You'll spend a lot of time counter-animating and bone-by-bone positioning if you use the metarig.

Comment: I'm personally fine with those drawbacks, auto IK counteracts the lack of inverse kinematics and counter animating doesn't matter that much since they're pretty simple skeletons. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @a1998ToyotaCorolla best of luck.  Since you're apparently a new user to Blender StackExchange, you might want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and perhaps upvote or accept my answer

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that. I tried upvoting earlier but it said "you need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote"